# Remove characters at the start of each line from csv file in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, insert

This CSV files contains the following data:

```
ID,GeneId,Searchterm,Type
"4,1253246,0,Gene Ontology
","4,1253246,0,Pathway
","4,1253246,0,Interaction
"
```

Every line starts with "," for some reason. Is there a way to remove them using PHP?

The code I use to insert the data into the CSV file is the following:

Using a foreach loop to insert data into an array called $csv_data

```
$csv_data[] = $name. "," .$Id1. "," .$search_term. ",".$sort."\r\n";
```

Only keep the unique data to insert in CSV file

```
$csv_data = array_unique($csv_data, SORT_REGULAR);
fputcsv($demofile, $csv_data);
```

Comment: Have you tried `$str = preg_replace("/\n\",", "\",\n", $str)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out why the symbol quotes were added to each line but when I use the following code, the problem is solved.

```
    fputcsv($demofile, array($name,$Id1,$search_term,$sort), ',', '"');
```

- ',' => is the delimiter
- '"' => is the enclosure

When I used $delimiter=',' or $enclosure='"', it wouldn't recognise parameters.